# How to add logo to stripe invoice pdf in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, invoice

How to add logo to stripe invoice pdf. I'm using laravel framework. Is there any way I can modify the blade file under vendor section? and commit the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `php artisan vendor:publish`.
This will create `vendor/cashier/receipt.blade.php` file in your `views` folder, which you can modify as per your requirement & commit.

Comment: This is fine but no matter what I do, the image just won't display. I am using format: <img src="{{ asset('img/logos/logo.png') }}" alt=""> The logo image exists but I'm getting error that the image can't be found. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably gave up / solved the issue long since @pdolinaj but for your question / anyone else searching, use base path when it's PDF - `{{ base_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'/img/logos/logo.png' }}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend Cashier's Invoice - `Laravel\Cashier\Invoice`.
2. Add `$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);` to pdf method:

```
public function pdf(array $data)
{
    if (! defined('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD')) {
        define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
    }

    $options = new Options;
    $options->setChroot(base_path());
    $options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);

    $dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
    $dompdf->setPaper(config('cashier.paper', 'letter'));
    $dompdf->loadHtml($this->view($data)->render());
    $dompdf->render();

    return $dompdf->output();
}
```